# How to extract substring with sed but first occurence only?

Tags: regex, linux, sed

Using `sed -n "s/.*\(\/.*\/\).*/\1/p` on `/string1/string2` produces string1, as expected.

However, using the same on `/string1/string2/string3` produces string2.

How can I print the first occurrence only, that is string1.

This does exactly what I wanted:

`sed -n "s/[^/]*\(\/[a-z]*\).*/\1/p"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 's/[^\/]*\(\/[^\/]*\/\).*/\1/p' file
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this sed:

```
sed -n 's|/\([^/]*\)/.*|\1|p'
```

Avoid escaping `/` by using an alternate delimiter.

Comment: +1. @rahat, the reason you're getting string2 is because the leading `.*` is *greedy*.

Comment: The problem with this is, when the string is something like:
random string /string1/string2/string3
It returns: random string string1. 
I would only like to extract /string1/

Comment: I have the same greedy issue but between two words. Instead of stopping at first word the command stops at last word. Any idea how to fix it? 
sed -e 's/.*Start\(.*\)End.*/\1

Answer (score 0):

perl's non-greedy regex quantifiers are handy:

```
perl -pe 's{.*?(/.*?/).*}{$1}' <<END
foobar/string1/string2/string3
END
```

```
/string1/
```

If you want to use <strike>bash</strike> shell:

```
str="foobar/string1/string2/string3"
string1=$( IFS=/; set -- $str; echo $2 )
```

Comment: Although, thats exactly what I want. Sadly, its for a bootscript and using perl is not an option.